# Получить файл с фронтенда(есть) и не сохраняя отправить на другой сервер

Tags: node.js

нужно получить с фронтенда файл, и не сохраняя отправить запросом на другой сервер

*пример отправки на бек*

[image: Отправка файла с фронта]

Но как обработать и отправить на другой сервер не сохраняя файл не могу понять

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable, https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer, https://github.com/mscdex/busboy, https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk. куда вам нужно его отправить?